# Checking for Internet connection does not work

Tags: swift, internet-connection

I'm trying to check for the internet connection in my app, and currently, I have this code:

```
  private let monitor: NWPathMonitor

        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            print(path.status)
            self?.isConnected = path.status == .satisfied
        }
```

However, this does not work. Specifically, the print does not print out the value in the debug console.

Could you please tell me what I have done wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: you could try removing the `=` such as  `monitor.pathUpdateHandler {...}`

Comment: I get quite a lot of errors after doing that...

Comment: you will have to show us more of your code for us to help you.
Is `monitor` some sort of `model`? Is `pathUpdateHandler` a `var` or a completion handler?
etc... In other words: Show a Minimal reproducible example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: I updated my question. Please refer to that.

Comment: ok, I see what you are trying to do. I assume you have : 
  `self.monitor = NWPathMonitor()` in the `init()`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is just like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is my (SwiftUI, sorry) test code that works for me.
You can probably recycle some of the code for your purpose.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Network

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("testing")
            .onAppear {
                let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "monitoring")
                monitor.start(queue: queue)
                monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
                     print(path.status)
                    if path.status == .satisfied {
                        print("-----> YES connected")
                    } else {
                        print("-----> NOT connected")
                    }
                 }
            }
    }
}
```

You can also use specific `monitor`, such as `let monitor = NWPathMonitor(requiredInterfaceType: .wifi)`